# Zurb Foundation mobile, Div element shows up when the sidebar menu is opened

Tags: php, html, zurb-foundation

Hi I am using zurb foundation and was trying to put two boxes using div's and used the following:

`<div class="small-12 large-3 columns">`

The issue is that everything under this div doesn't show up when you open the website on the mobile phone but when you hit click the menu button, the menu is a side bar on the 
left hand side;

To see what happens please visit [Link](http://cc.doorfree.com/) through your phone to see what i mean.

The elements under this div show up.

I am not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your working code so far. People are not going to visit external sites and dig through your source code.

Comment: Hi Sorry about that. But it's hard for me to put the company's code here. And its over 400 lines of code.. Is there a better way to do that.

Comment: @user3924701 400 lignes of code just for that ! simplify the problem, and post your code.

Comment: God ! don't go on the link he provides !if he can't provide more code then too bad for him...